# Signalr From Windows Services to Blazor Server App

Tags: service, blazor, signalr, usb, rfid

I need help or guidance to implement a solution to be able to use an RFID USB (Acr120U) from the blazor server app. Think of a SignalR service on the clients pc. I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.